# How to run curl from android java

Tags: java, android, curl

I am successfully executing from the Windows CMD console the following instruction:

> `curl --user on:on --form "imgupload_front=@C:\Users\franc\Downloads\miau.jpg" --form code=8411916819976 --form imagefield=front --form user_id=id --form password=pass https://fr.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/product_image_upload.pl`

I have added internet, internal and external storage permissions. Also: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

When I run it in android studio I change the image path to: Internal memory\DCIM\Screenshots\a.jpg

Is there a possibility to execute this instruction with java from android?

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: You are trying to upload a file that is on your windows pc. But you Android app on your Android device has no access to files on your pc. Or on mines.

Comment: Please search before asking, else the question may be closed. As already suggested, path `C:\Users\franc\Downloads\miau.jpg` is just wrong.

Comment: Regarding putting it as a duplicate, I consider that it is not so. In the questions you show, there is no sending a file to a certain key. Just an upload of a file but not to a certain key. And here is the error.

Comment: On the other hand, good observation, I have already corrected the route, but it keeps giving me an error in android. In the Windows CMD console it works perfectly.